# How can i create a separate folder in REACT for my Axios routes, that are connected to my node.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

Hello I trying to create a separate folder for my axios routes. I do not want them inside of my components file in React.

I have tried this under the following folder, separate from my components folder. src > actions > authentication

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const signupUser = (user, history) => dispatch => {
  axios.post('http://localhost:3000/signup', user)
  console.log(user)
    .then(res => history.push('/login'))
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);

    });
};
```

Inside the Signup.js component I have the following, that is not currently working

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { signupUser } from '../actions/authentication';
import axios from 'axios';

let today = new Date();
let date = today.getFullYear()+ '-' +  (today.getMonth()+1)+ '-' +today.getDate();




class Signup extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      first_name: '',
      last_name: '',
      user_name: '',
      email: '',
      password: '',
      created_on: date,
      isSignedup: false
    }

    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);

    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleInputChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    })
    console.log(this.state);
  }

  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const user = {

      first_name: this.state.first_name,
      last_name: this.state.last_name,
      email: this.state.email,
      user_name: this.state.user_name,
      password: this.state.password,
      created_on: this.state.created_on,
      isSignedup: !this.state.isSignedup
    }
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data);
      this.props.history.replace('/login');
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    })
  }
```

It only works in my components > Signup.js if I have the actual axios route inside the component as follows:

```
handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    axios.post('http://localhost:3000/signup', {

      first_name: this.state.first_name,
      last_name: this.state.last_name,
      email: this.state.email,
      user_name: this.state.user_name,
      password: this.state.password,
      created_on: this.state.created_on,
      isSignedup: !this.state.isSignedup
    })
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data);
      this.props.history.replace('/login');
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    })
  }
```

The error I keep receiving is that .then is not a function. Can someone please help me with this issue? Thank you in advance.

Comment: In `handleSubmit` in `Signup.js` you have `const user = { ... }.then(...)`. Is this a typo just in the question or your actual code? You probably meant to do something like `const user = {...}; signupUser(user).then(...)`. There are some issues in `signupUser` as well... The method should return the promise `return axios.post('...', user).then(...)`.

Comment: Yes that is an error so sorry about that. ;(

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error `.then is not a function` because of this code:

```
const user = {

  first_name: this.state.first_name,
  last_name: this.state.last_name,
  email: this.state.email,
  user_name: this.state.user_name,
  password: this.state.password,
  created_on: this.state.created_on,
  isSignedup: !this.state.isSignedup
}
.then
```

That's not valid javascript. Assigning an object to a variable does not create a promise. You have to actually call on `signupUser`.

Furthermore, I don't understand why you pass dispatch into your signup function if you are never calling on it?

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track with your thinking as it makes the design of your application a bit more modular.

You could create a folder called `apis/`, it doesn't have to be called that but I am just giving you an example. Then inside there create a file called `myjson.js`, again call it what you think is best. Inside that folder you will have something like this:

```
import axios from "axios";

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: "https://api.myjson.com"
});
```

Then you could implement that inside your action creator as `myJson.post()`

You could also do something like this:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const ROOT_URL =
  "https://exampleurl.com";

class SignUpForm extends Component {
  state = { phone: "" };

  handleSubmit = () => {
    axios
      .post(`${ROOT_URL}/createUser`, {
        phone: this.state.phone
      })
      .then(() => {
        axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}/requestOneTimePassword`, {
          phone: this.state.phone
        });
      });
  };
```

The above of course is based on a one time password type of authentication so tailor it to the logic of your architecture.

Also, if you are going to use a `constructor` function with `super(props)` you need to pass `props` into it like I just did.

You can avoid all that by using ES7 and just assigning

```
state = {
  first_name: '',
  last_name: '',
  user_name: '',
  email: '',
  password: '',
  created_on: date,
  isSignedup: false
}
```

You are already using an arrow function in your `handleSubmit`, so there is no need to do this: `this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);` The arrow function is taking care of the context of `this`.

We can take it further and refactor that `handleSubmit` function to look cleaner by using ES7 async/await syntax like so:

```
handleSubmit = async () => {
 await axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}/createUser`, {
   phone: this.state.phone
 });
 await axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}/requestOneTimePassword`, {
   phone: this.state.phone
 });
};
```

And to handle errors, since we are using async/await, we can wrap everything awaited with a try/catch block like so:

```
handleSubmit = async () => {
    try {
      await axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}/createUser`, {
        phone: this.state.phone
      });

      await axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}/requestOneTimePassword`, {
        phone: this.state.phone
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
```

So this way you can catch and console log the error.

And try/catch is not new with ES2015/16/17, it's been around for a while.

Essentially, whenever you want to handle errors thrown by a request managed by the await statement we can wrap it with try/catch statement.

The failed network request response will be passed in as the error object and we can console log it to see what happens.